# Check file is not tampered with

Tags: c, file, hash, checksum, rdp

Suppose my software generates a file and user downloads it, I want to make sure when the user opens/executes the file he does not tamper with the file.

The file in context here is an rdp file it basically is a text file and has arguments for the Microsoft rdp connection separated by lines ex:

redirectclipboard:i:1

redirectdrives:i:0

full address:s:10.10.10.10:3389

How do I make sure its not tampered with? My software will be acting as proxy between the RDP server and user
I am thinking of using checksum/hash but is there any easier way to implement this?

Comment: Normal approach: SHA2-256 hash or some other kind of cryptographic signature. There is no "easier" approach other than, say, trusting the user!

Comment: If I download a file to my computer, I can do _anything_ with it, and you cannot stop me. However, as long as you don't allow me to upload it again, the original is unchanged. So, what do you want?

Comment: "How do I make sure its not tampered with" Tampered by who?

Comment: Need to make sure the user/client has not modified what is downloaded by him.
When he opens the file it is proxied through  my software

Comment: @thebusybee After you download the file it is executed through my software (it acts as a proxy in between and the network traffic flows through it) I just want to make sure he is executing the file he had downloaded

Comment: Let's see. Can the user look at the file? Can the user open notepad and type? What are you going to do with that?

Comment: What is the threat you try to mitigate?

Comment: @thebusybee The threat I am trying to mitigate is in this case suppose the file was downloaded with rdp option to disallow the user to redirectclipboard, the file will contain something like redirectclipboard:i:0. I don't want the user to change it to 1 and gain the permission, although this can be controlled from the RDP server side I needed control from the user side itself (for scalability)

Comment: Understood, mostly. (Please add this to your question.) So you want to control options from the user side, but don't want the user to fiddle with the options. Hm, it sounds that you need "security by obscurity", it will stop most users, until one expert publishes a text or software. This method "works" only if the ratio of work-around to benefit is high enough. Good luck!

Comment: "I don't want the user to change it to 1". Can the user just type his config file in a text editor and run rdp with it? How are you planning to stop it from happening?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.
The user's rdp file will go through my software (acts as something like a proxy)
I am thinking of storing a hash/checksum(encrypted) of the original rdp file data in the downloaded file (as one of the fields) and when the user executes/opens the file I want to verify if the hash/checksum matches (will close connection if it doesn't match)

Comment: If your software opens the file, and runs an rdp client using it as a config, you cryptographically sign it when you send it, check the signature when you open it, then clip the signature and pass to the rdp client. This will probably not stop a determined attacker though.